# Replacing Malware System Apps with Clean Versions of Apps

Tags: security, malware, system, system-apps, builds

I have many times found devices or ROMs that have malware installed as system apps.  This thread is intended to define a recurring problem and discuss and determine solutions.

**Background:**
In many cases malware apps can simply and directly be removed with root privileges.  A complication, however, arises when the app to be removed is: a rather important app, necessary to run or boot the operating system, or an app of its kind is necessary to run or boot the operating system.  Only removing such apps may resolve the malware problem, but creates other major problems such as an inability to meaningfully operate the Android environment or an inability to boot the Android operating system.  A few typical examples of such apps are the Settings app and the Package Installer app.

Wherefore, to perform a proper repair, a malware app must instead be patched to remove the malware or replaced with another clean and compatible app.

For basic Android apps, such as the Settings app and Package Installer app, that are malware infected, I would think that the best course of action would be to replace the infected app with a clean AOSP version or clean OEM version.  Using the OEM version of the app would only be acceptable if the app were available and the OEM is believed to not have or be the source of the malware.

**The Problem Being Considered:**
For a malware infected system app to be replaced with a clean AOSP version, my impression of the most obvious option that would be most likely to work would be to build Android from source against the target device and for the same architecture and Android version as the malware-infected system, and then donate its apps as replacements for the malware-infected apps and replace the malware-infected apps.  Unfortunately, while the method should be effective, it comes with considerable costs.  The sizes of the various Android source codes are quite large and it can take a rather long time to acquire and process it.  It is worth considering other options.

**Questions to Resolve or Related to Problem:**
Instead of building Android from source against the target device and for the same architecture and Android version as the malware-infected, AOSP-based system to use as a source for donating replacement apps:

Should it be sufficient to use apps from an AOSP or AOSP-based build of Android, such as LineageOS, with the same Android version and architecture as the build of Android of the infected device?

Should it be sufficient to use apps from an AOSP or AOSP-based build of Android for a different device, but with the same Android version and architecture as the infected device?  Is the matching of the SoC or processors of the donating Android build and the target Android build important for donation app compatibility purposes?

Is it acceptable to use a build of Android of a different minor version to acquire an app for donation to the malware-infected app build?  (For example, malware-infected build may be of Android version 7.0, but other, clean Android build may be of Android 7.1.2)

Can just single Android system app be compiled?  If so, would it still require acquiring the source code for the entire Android version?

Are there any generic, pre-built offerings of Android that may be used to donate replacement apps?  If so, where?

Any other recommendations or things I may not have thought of?

Comment: If the malware is smart enough to enter `/system ` and infect system apps, it may be capable of hiding itself in other places in system too. Therefore, IMO, it's better to format the entire system partition and flash the original ROM for the device. That takes care of the infected apps as also eliminates the possibility of it being hidden and not detected in the system partition. This is much easier than the alternatives you present

Comment: I agree with @beeshyams here, who but might have missed one fact: that "original ROM" (referred to by OP as "OEM version") might actually be the infected one – in which case it would require a complete 3rd party ROM of trustable source (e.g. LineageOS) for the exact device. But yes, a full ROM flash is recommended: where there sits one evil, another one usually sits close to it.

Comment: I would clarify (I had forgotten to separately and explicitly reemphasize it in my initial post) the following assumptions/considerations with regards to the questions I had posed:

With regards to the possibility of using the original ROM or OEM firmware to repair:
1. The original ROM or stock ROM has the malware. Simply wiping the current ROM and flashing the original ROM would restore the malware.
2. If the original ROM does not have the malware, the original ROM is not available.

While both the above possibilities are of interest, I am most interested in the first option.

Comment: Flashing malware-free firmware to replace malware is preferable, but the option is often not reasonably available.  Even where a third-party ROM is available to flash, it may lack necessary features present in the original ROM.

The definition of malware includes spyware.

Comment: Common examples of malware infected stock systems:
1. OEMs agree to include a suite of Google Apps spyware and provide it as part of the system.
2. OEMs (oftentimes Chinese) that produce Android devices directly for ODM clients include malware in the ROMs on the devices, though not necessarily by client request.
3. OEMs, otherwise may include (knowingly or not) malware to spy on the user, likely via deals or interaction with other parties such as governments.

Of the common malware-infected systems examples above, at least option 1. is reasonable to attempt repair.

Comment: The questions I had posed have more to do with Android build compatibility.  They are to determine whether other Android builds may donate system apps to replace a build's systems apps.  Creation of such builds and cost management of such is also explored.  Malware removal (particularly uninstalling Google Apps, while retaining a working system) is thought to be a typical scenario where these things are considered.